# Task '\' not found in root project while setting up schema.json in Apollo using Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

Am trying to get a schema.json file using Apollo's [downloadApolloSchema task](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/android/essentials/get-started-kotlin/#download-your-schemajson-file:%7E:text=downloadApolloSchema%20task) as shown in the example. Here is the code which am running in the terminal:

```
gradlew downloadApolloSchema \
  --endpoint="https://api.github.com/graphql" \
  --schema="E:\Developement\Android Kotlin Projects\IssueTracker\app\holder" \
  --header="Authorization: Bearer myactualtoken"
```

The Error am getting:

```
BUILD FAILED in 4s
> Configure project :app
Could not find google-services.json while looking in [src/nullnull/debug, src/debug/nullnull, src/nullnull, src/debug, src/nullnullDebug]
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
Could not find google-services.json while looking in [src/nullnull/release, src/release/nullnull, src/nullnull, src/release, src/nullnullRelease]
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
Task '\' not found in root project 'MsgShareApp'.

* Try:
Run gradlew tasks to get a list of available tasks. Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get
full insights.
```

I already have google-services.json file in this directory.

[Path to Google-Services](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5cyx7.png)

Comment: Shouldn't  --endpoint="https://api.github.com/graphql"\ have a space before \ ?

Comment: Thanks @ Laksitha Ranasingha for pointing it out, I've fixed it but the error is still the same